# override built-in json-loader in webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have my own json-loader which I want to use instead of the built-in loader. This used to work in webpack-3; in webpack-4 my loader gets called
but the results get passed to the built-in loader, which then errors out because what it's being fed is JS source, not json. How can I prevent the buit-in json-loader being called? My webpack.cofig.ts looks like this:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack'
import * as path from 'path'

const config = {
  mode: 'production',
  node: { fs: 'empty' },
  resolveLoader: {
    alias: { 'custom-json-loader': 'zotero-plugin/loader/json' },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [ { test: /\.json$/, use: [ 'custom-json-loader' ] } ],
  },

  // ...
}

export default config
```

Comment: I think this is going to affect all loaders that convert between module types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395913/webpack-4-change-a-modules-type-in-a-loader

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to tell webpack that your loader emits javascript and not json.
To do so you must add `type: "javascript/auto"` to your loader configuration:

```
module: {
    rules: [ 
         { 
            test: /\.json$/, 
            use: [ 'custom-json-loader' ] ,
            type: "javascript/auto"
         }
   ]
}
```

[Changelog for Webpack 4](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.0.0)