# Webpack 4 - Change a module's type in a loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader

Webpack 4 introduces module types, allowing better handling of JSON, CSS, ES6 modules, etc.

Some loaders, like [messageformat-loader](https://github.com/messageformat/loader), take in source of one type (in this case JSON), but output a different type (in this case JS). This currently breaks in Webpack 4.

```
ERROR in ./src/messages.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

**How can a loader notify webpack of a module type change?**

I tried `this._module.type = 'javascript/auto'` in my loader but it had no effect.

As a workaround, the end user can add `type: 'javascript/auto'` to the webpack config for the loader, but this seems like a leak of implementation details. Plus, it wouldn't work in the case where the user wants to pipe the output of this loader into another that's expecting JS.

Any loader that changes between source types will be affected, like [val-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/val-loader), [to-string-loader](https://github.com/gajus/to-string-loader), [apply-loader](https://github.com/mogelbrod/apply-loader), etc. I think even [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) and the like will be affected since they convert from ES6 modules to ES5 code, which are now different module types.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052935/override-built-in-json-loader-in-webpack-4

Comment: Originally reported as a bug: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6572

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to this problem in the source of the [copy-files-loader](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/cb36619cb728d11dcb53c88c1c647251d43bb43b/lib/webpack/copy-files-loader.js). Essentially you need the following in your loader:

```js
const LoaderDependency = require('webpack/lib/dependencies/LoaderDependency');

module.exports = function (source) {
   const requiredType = 'javascript/auto';
   const factory = this._compilation.dependencyFactories.get(LoaderDependency);
   this._module.type = requiredType;
   this._module.generator = factory.getGenerator(requiredType);
   this._module.parser = factory.getParser(requiredType);

   // do your transforms on `source` here

   return `export default ${JSON.stringify(source)}`;
}
```